# spring boot - multiple data sources in one application for a single entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple test databases and I want my application to access the data in each database.  I have my DataSources setup like so:

```
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.test01")
  public DataSource test01() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.test02")
  public DataSource test02() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
```

Now I have verified (by marking 1 primary and not the other one) that I can access both databases independently with my "user" class

```
package foo;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User {

  //columns go here     
  ...
}
```

and my interface

```
package foo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String lastName);
}
```

and my controller

```
package foo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("user", repository.findByUsername("admin"));
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Now I want to do within my application is

`test01.repository.findByUsername("admin") == test02.repository.findByUsername("admin")`